# c++ Compiler can't use my overloaded < operator for bitset key comparison

Tags: c++, overloading, grammar

I know I can always use the set(comp) constructor to initialize the comparasion function for my set .

But I usually prefer overloading the **operator <** .

So when I want to use bitsets as set keys ,I use this code below .

```
#include <bitset>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

bool operator<(const std::bitset<128>& x, const std::bitset<128>& y)
{
  return false;//show the brief idea of overloading operator< ,never mind .
};

int main()
{
  set<bitset<128> > s{ bitset<128>() };
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me these compile errors below .

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::bitset<128>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   2   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::bitset<128>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   3   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'const std::bitset<128>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   4   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const std::bitset<128>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   5   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::bitset<128>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   6   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::bitset<128>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   7   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::bitset<128>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   8   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::bitset<128>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
Error   9   error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::bitset<128>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef  193 1   test
```

But this piece of code compiles .

```
#include <bitset>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct wrapper
{
  std::bitset<128> a;
};

bool operator<(const std::bitset<128>& x, const std::bitset<128>& y)
{
  return false;
};

bool operator<(const wrapper& x, const wrapper& y)
{
  return x.a<y.a;
};

int main()
{
  set<wrapper> s{ wrapper() };
  return 0;
}
```

I wonder why .

Comment: The `std::set` code finds the comparison function via Argument Dependent Lookup. Except for a general prohibition against introducing new things in namespace `std` you could define it there, since that's where `std::bitset` lives. But better just pass comparator function to constructor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has everything to do with the complexities of name lookup in C++.

By default, `std::set` uses `std::less<Key>` as its comparator, whose implementation looks approximately like:

```
template <class K>
struct less {
    bool operator()(K const& lhs, K const& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;  // (*)
    }
};
```

The marked line is where `<` is actually called. To find which `<` to call, we look in the scope of the template definition (which will not find your `operator<`) and we look in the associated namespaces of the arguments (which is `std::`, and your `operator<` is not in that namespace. It would actually be illegal to add it to that namespace too). Since neither of those lookups will find anything, the code is ill-formed.

Your second example fixes the argument-dependent part of the lookup: now there *is* an `operator<` in the associated namespace of the argument (which is `::`), and it will be found.

Note that you can *still* have a `std::set` of `std::bitset<N>`. You just have to provide a custom comparator to the class template.

Answer (score 1):

Operators must be overloaded in the namespace of the class in question:

```
namespace std {
   bool operator<(const bitset<128>& x, const bitset<128>& y)
   {
      return false;//show the brief idea of overloading operator< ,never mind .
   };
}

using namespace std;

// The rest of the code in the question.
```

Verified with gcc 6.1.1

Comment: But don't introduce new things in namespace `std`. You're allowed to specialize there. But not this.